# MS Sql Full-text search vs. LIKE expression

Tags: sql, database, full-text-search, sql-like

I'm currently looking for a way to search a big database (500MB - 10GB or more on 10 tables) with a lot of different fields(nvarchars and bigints).
Many of the fields, that should be searched are not in the same table.

An example: A search for '5124 Peter' should return all items, that ...

- have an ID with 5124 in it,
- have 'Peter' in the title or description
- have item type id with 5124 in it
- created by a user named 'peter' or a user whose id has 5124 in it
- created by a user with '5124' or 'peter' in his street address.

How should i do the search? I read that the full-text search of MS-Sql is a lot more performant than a query with the LIKE keyword and i think the syntax is more clear, but i think it cant search on bigint(id) values and i read it has performance problems with indexing and therefore slows down inserts to the DB. In my project there will be more inserting than reading, so this could be a matter.

Thanks in advance,
Marks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you're going to get the performance you need out of MS SQL; you're going to need to construct very complex queries to cover all the data/tables that you're going to be searching, and you have the added encumbrance of writing data to the database at the same time as you are querying it.

I would suggest you look at either Apache Solr (http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) or Lucene (http://lucene.apache.org).  Solr is built on top of Lucene, both can be used to create an inverted file index, basically like the index in the back of book (term 1 appears in documents 1, 3, 7, etc.)  Solr is a search-engine-in-a-box, and has several mechanisms that will let you tell it how and where to index data. Lucene is more lower-level, and will let you set up your indexing and searching architecture with more flexibility.

The good thing about Solr is that it's available as a web service, so if you're not familiar with Java, you can find a Solr client in the language of your choice, and write indexing and searching code in whatever language suits you.  Here's a link to a list of client libraries for Solr, including some in C# http://wiki.apache.org/solr/IntegratingSolr  That's where I'd start.

Answer (score 3):

You could try a standalone search engine, such as Sphinx Search:

http://www.sphinxsearch.com/index.html

or Apache Solr:

http://lucene.apache.org/solr/

Comment: I have to look at these when i have more time, but i would like to know a solution if staying with only MS SQL Server.

Comment: You could use full-text search to search non integer (ID) columns.  Then extract any numbers from the search query, and use standard SQL select queries to test the integer (ID) columns.  There are a few techniques to help mitigate indexing performance issues.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/933351/ms-sql-server-2000-slow-full-text-indexing.

Answer (score 0):

Full-text search is definitely more performant than like expression. What you can do is create a full-text index on a view instead of a table, and since it's just the index that gets searched that can save table joins later which can speed things up a bit. The view would also allow you to convert the bigint columns to varchar which can then get indexed, say by concatenating all the columns that are to be searched together as one varchar column. To do this you need to create a view with SCHEMABINDING and select at least one column that is unique and create a clustered unique index on it.

As for the effects on full-text on insert performance, I haven't noticed much of an impact on bulk insert myself but I see from stackoverflow question 3301470, someone mention that performance was slow on sql 2005 but that in sql 2008 that's now fixed. This is because it now updates the index after the bulk insert instead of after every individual row insert (I'm running 2008). If you are running 2005 then to improve you can disable change tracking just for the bulk insert and manually call update index after.